# change in velocity affecting composition of the gas inside the object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, acceleration

So I was wondering if changing the acceleration of a chamber filled with air would affect the composition of the air inside? For example if a large chamber was filled with air and was very rapidly accelerated, would the gas contain a higher concentration of the heavier gases in the back of the container, compared to the front? And vice versa if the container was slowing down. If I can make anything more clear please do ask.

Comment: Inducing acceleration is the same as changing the effective gravity acting on the system. I think gravity does induce a segregation based on molecular weight.

Comment: Yes, gas centrifuges do this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_centrifuge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Acceleration is equivalent to a gravitational field. Even with a gas consisting of only one type of molecule, there is a pressure gradient in a gravitational field, because the gas below must support that above, and a pressure gradient requires a density gradient. (Molecules which are closer collide more often and exert more force.)

The density gradient is different for different types of molecules. For heavy molecules there is a significantly increased density towards the bottom, while for light molecules at the same temperature the density is almost uniform. So for a mixture of gases there would be a variation in its composition.

The atmosphere of Earth follows this general trend of heaviest molecules at the bottom and lightest at the top. But the atmosphere is complicated by a temperature gradient and by high-energy cosmic rays incident from the top which cause reactions (eg dissociation, ionization), so there are anomalies. See [Composition of Earth's atmosphere with elevation](http://wordpress.mrreid.org/2014/08/01/the-composition-of-earths-atmosphere-with-elevation/).

Answer (score -2):

No it wont have an effect. If it were to have an effect then on Earth too CO2 being heavier should have been found only in lower layers but its not true. This is because gases have a property of diffusion which overpowers the effect of gravity or acceleration on them.

Comment: but then how can you do those science experiments where you can extinguish a flame using carbon dioxide as seen here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUnPUMSfnzE or that the really high altitudes does generally have lighter elements such as helium while it isnt as present at sea level

Comment: @Nikita thats a nice question but still has an answer. Diffusion is not a rapid process, this reason might not convince you. But there's another justification that in a candle there are conventional currents that exist which drive the carbon particles upwards.

Comment: I dont see how the candles conventional currents would make it extinguish as seen in the video. Also wouldnt the conventional currents be the explanation for why the earths atmosphere is more mixed than if it was just placed inside a container?